# WPF gif animation stops when another Tab is selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on WPFAnimatedGiff.dll [[CodePlex]](https://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/documentation) for animating a gif. I have multiple tabs in my WPF Window. gif image is displayed in a TabControl. The gif is animating properly when the application is executed, but when I select another tab the animation stops, and doesn't starts until restart.

my code is given below

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem Header="Home">
                 <Image x:Name="Animation" Stretch="UniformToFill" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{StaticResource gifImage}" Opacity="0.25">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Page2" >

            </TabItem>


        </TabControl>
```

kindly guide me how can I resolve this issue

Comment: You could try and switch to a file reference instead of a static resource to rule out that as a cause as well.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I have tried it but same issue

Comment: In that case there is only one solution: read the code of the library, download the library sources and step through the code or add lots of tracing info (stepping through might not work due to the focus changing that might be related to the problem) and start hunting the bug (if it is a bug).